# R programming(sum of products)

Tags: r

i'm working on how to find sum of products of two dataframes.

```
data<-w1 w2 w3 w4
      4   6  8  5
```

where w1 w2 w3 w4 are column names

and I have one more dataframe

```
data2<-p1 p2 p3 p4
        3  4  5  6
        5  6  8  4
        4  6  6  8
        3  5  8  9
```

my result should be like this:

```
result <- w1*P1+w2*p2+w3*p3*w4*p4    

result1 <- 4*3+6*4+8*5+5*6   # result on row 1

result2 <- 4*5+6*6+8*8+5*4   # result on row 2
```

and so on for each row in data2

how to do this in general

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fastest way is to come back to `R` linear algebra (even more is you have big `data.frame`'s):

```
> as.matrix(data2) %*% unlist(data)
#     [,1] 
#[1,]  106
#[2,]  140 
#[3,]  140
#[4,]  151
```

Or `sweep`:

```
> rowSums(sweep(as.matrix(data2), 2, unlist(data), `*`))
#[1] 106 140 140 151
```

**Data**

```
data=data.frame(a=4,b=6,c=8,d=5)
data2=data.frame(a=c(3,5,4,3),b=c(4,6,6,5),c=c(5,8,6,8),d=c(6,4,8,9))
```

Comment: Or `tcrossprod(unlist(data),as.matrix(data2))`

Answer (score 3):

You could use `mapply`:

```
df1 <- data.frame(w1 = 4, w2 = 6, w3 = 8, w4 = 5)
df2 <- data.frame(p1 = c(3, 5, 4, 3), p2 = c(4, 6, 6, 5), 
                  p3 = c(5, 8, 6, 8), p4 = c(6, 4, 8, 9))
```

This multiplies each element of df2 with each element of df1 (by element I mean column - the data frame is treated as a list in this context):

```
> (tmp <- mapply(`*`, df2, df1))
     p1 p2 p3 p4
[1,] 12 24 40 30
[2,] 20 36 64 20
[3,] 16 36 48 40
[4,] 12 30 64 45
>sum(tmp)
[1] 537
```

**Edit** If you want to get the sum of each row from the above matrix you can use either `apply(tmp, 1, sum)` or `rowSums`:

```
> rowSums(tmp)
[1] 106 140 140 151
```